# My iPhone update

Tags: iphone

When I tried to update my iPhone 6, it is supposed to download about 2.97 GB but it changes to 73 MB all of a sudden, a couple of days ago.

What’s the cause of that problem?

Comment: What is your current iOS version? Where did you see the 73 MB figure?

Comment: @udhy Tags ;p Them and the title should be better I believe. I am waiting for iOS version though, to update altogether.

Comment: @ankii: Agreed mate.